# when I remove the "int e = 0;" I get seg fault

Tags: c, string, serialization, text, memcpy

I have the following program in c, when I remove the "int e = 0;" I get seg fault, anyone knows why? it's not even being used?

The second thing is what is the best method here to get the first 3 int? I'm using memcpy but it's not working correctly for the first one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int test()
{    
unsigned char string1[] = {0xce,0x01,0x00,0x00,0xe9,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x74,0x65,0x73,0x74};
//0xce,0x01,0x00,0x00 this should be the first int
//0xe9,0x00,0x00,0x00 Second int
//0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00 third int, the rest is the text "test"
    int e = 0;// when I comment this one I get Segmentation fault 
    unsigned int int1 = 0;
    unsigned int int2 = 0;
    unsigned int int3 = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int size = 0;
    size = sizeof(length);
    memcpy(&int1, string1, length); printf("%d\n",int1); //should be 461
    length += size;
    memcpy(&int2, &string1[length], length);  printf("%d\n",int2); //shoud be 233
    length += size;
    memcpy(&int3, &string1[length], length);  printf("%d\n",int3); //should be 1 
    length += size;
    printf("%s\n",&string1[length]);//text should be test

}

int main()
{
test();
}
```

output is below when "int e = 0;" is present

```
0
233
1
test
```

output is below when "int e = 0;" is commented

```
0
233
1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing zero, then `sizeof (length)`, then `2* sizeof(length)` as the third argument of `memcpy`.  That's probably not what you intended, and the last one is too large for your destination.

Use `sizeof (int1)`, `sizeof (int2)`, `sizeof (int3)` instead of `length` (which is actually an offset not a length) and your problem should go away.

---

Note, as Floris pointed out, you'd then have another problem since `%s` in a printf format specifier looks for a terminating NUL byte and you don't have one.

Comment: To elaborate, the extra int declaration provided enough safety space on the stack for you to overrun it safely.

Comment: @Curt: It did in his particular test, but of course the stack layout is not guaranteed.

Comment: @BenVoigt you missed the last printf, which would cause an error anyway, but yes depending on the memory layout it could be one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

You need to null-terminate your string. When you declare `e` it happens to occupy a spot in memory right after the string, and provides the null termination for you. You need to add `'\0'` as the last value in the string being passed in, and all will be well...

Answer (score 0):

Memory overrun on:

```
printf("%s\n",&string1[length])
```

Your string is not properly terminated with a \0.
The e=0 terminates your string.

In addition you are using length instead of size.

Should be:

```
int test()
{    
unsigned char string1[] = {0xce,0x01,0x00,0x00,0xe9,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x74,0x65,0x73,0x74, 0x00};
//0xce,0x01,0x00,0x00 this should be the first int
//0xe9,0x00,0x00,0x00 Second int
//0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00 third int, the rest is the text "test"
    int e = 0;// when I comment this one I get Segmentation fault 
    unsigned int int1 = 0;
    unsigned int int2 = 0;
    unsigned int int3 = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int size = 0;
    size = sizeof(unsigned int);
    memcpy(&int1, string1, size); printf("%d\n",int1); //should be 461
    length += size;
    memcpy(&int2, &string1[length], size);  printf("%d\n",int2); //shoud be 233
    length += size;
    memcpy(&int3, &string1[length], size);  printf("%d\n",int3); //should be 1 
    length += size;
    printf("%s\n",&string1[length]);//text should be test

}
```

Note the `0x00` termination on string1 and the use of size instead of length in memcpy.